# Pass a 2D array as an argument:

Tags: arrays, vba

```
Dim arrS(1000, 6) As String

Sub FromHere()
'(I've already filled the array and just want to pass it from here):

 Call ToThere(someArray)
End Sub

Sub ToThere(someArray)
 MsgBox "And I want to use it:  " & someArray(2, 2)
End Sub
```

Everything I'm trying is redlining, won't make it out of the editor.

Can you show me how this should be declared/dimensioned at the top and within each statement so it'll just run?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Sub ToThere(someArray() as string)
```